# Python class variable changed a function into a method, why?

Tags: python, class, types, scope, metaclass

Why does Python turn a free function into an unbound method upon assignment to a class variable?

```
def make_func(s):
    def func(x):
        return '%s-%d' % (s, x)
    return func

class Foo(object):
    foofunc = make_func('foo')
```

So this works as expected: (returns "dog-1")

```
make_func('dog')(1)
```

But this fails with:

```
Foo.foofunc(1)
```

`TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`

Upon closer inspection, Python turned the "inner" function `func` inside `make_func` into a method, but since there's no `self`, this method will never work. Why does Python do this?

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(Foo, inspect.ismethod)
[('foofunc', <unbound method Foo.func>)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python can't tell "how" you assigned a method to a class attribute.  There is no difference between this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def meth():
        pass
```

and this

```
def func():
    pass

class Foo(object):
    meth = func
```

In both cases, the result is that a function object is assigned to a class attribute named `'meth'`.  Python can't tell whether you assigned it by defining the function inside the class, or by "manually" assigning it using `meth = func`.  It can only see the "end result", which is an attribute whose value is a function.  Either way, once the function is in the class, it is converted to a method via the normal process that notices functions in class definitions and makes them into methods.

Comment: proof is in the pudding: `foofunc = staticmethod(make_func('foo'))` gives you the behavior you expected

Comment: Hmm, it probably create the class by setting an dictionary key of 'meth' to the definition of 'func', which it then transformed into a method. Quite unexpected, I must say.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Foo(object):
    foofunc = make_func('foo')
```

foofunc is a class variable, not a method (for which you need the 'def'). And you initialize it with the result of make_func(...), so it won't change again.

If you want to *call* Foo.foofunc, you need to assign `foofunc = make_func` without a parameter.